Why did Sofia execute the thief in "The Penguin"?
Near the end of episode 1 of The Penguin (2024 TV series), while Oswald is tied to a chair naked, Sofia Falcone executes a thief who was a key witness against Oswald.
However, this doesn't make sense to me. The thief was still valuable in order to confront Oswald's story and shed some light on her brother's disappearance.
Why did Sofia execute the thief?

Several factors are at play here:

The car rim thief had already provided crucial information by admitting he saw Oz near the Iceberg Lounge on the night her brother disappeared (who was actually killed by Oz). So, from Sofia's perspective, he had served his purpose.

Sofia was trying to make a point to Oz. She wanted to demonstrate that Oz talking his way out of trouble would cost someone else their life.

This scene is meant to showcase Sofia Falcone's unstable and dangerous nature. Remember, she's just been released from Arkham Asylum, which speaks volumes about her mental state.

Sofia's plan was to torture the information out of Oz. In fact, she was in the process of doing so when Victor's timely intervention (sending the car with Alberto's body in the trunk) interrupted her. Without this interruption, Oz might have cracked under the pressure and revealed everything.



Throughout the 1st episode, Sofia is portrayed as someone that knows well how to calculate each action. IMHO, it seems she miscalculated this move.
